# FTPWebRequest.GetResponse timeout on server, not on local debug

Tags: vb.net, azure, ftp, timeout, ftpwebrequest

I made a Azure cloud service which download files from a FTP server and then upload them to an Azure storage.
When I debug my service, everything works fine, the files are uploaded to the storage. Once I published the service, I received an error (not always, but 4 times of 5 try):
    "System.Net.WebException: The operation has timed out."
The line number of the error correspond to the line

```
Dim response As FtpWebResponse = CType(request.GetResponse, FtpWebResponse)
```

Why does it work on local debug and not from cloud ? 
For information, there is no proxy or what. It seems to work in a random way.
A part of my code :

```
 'Request
    Dim request As FtpWebRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create(Configuration.Address + suffixPath), FtpWebRequest)
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile

    'Login and pwd
    request.Credentials = New NetworkCredential(Configuration.Login, Configuration.Password)
    request.UsePassive = False
    request.KeepAlive = True
    request.Timeout = Integer.MaxValue
    request.ReadWriteTimeout = Integer.MaxValue

    Try
        Dim response As FtpWebResponse = CType(request.GetResponse, FtpWebResponse)
        Dim stream As Stream = response.GetResponseStream
...
```

Thx all

--- EDIT ----

I found this article :
http://feedback.azure.com/forums/217313-networking-dns-traffic-manager-vpn-vnet/suggestions/3346609-icmp-support-for-azure-websites-roles-cloud-serv

It's a suggestion to add ICMP traffic for Azure VMs, Services...

I tried to do a simple ping test from my Azure Cloud Service to my FTP Server, with a Timeout of 30 seconds, I received ... a timeout error immediatly.

Do you think guys that is a possible explanation of my problem ?
If it does, is there any means to download file from ftp by passing thru UDP or something else ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Finally found the solution to my problem.

The restriction for ICMP traffic inside a Azure VM or Service was the thing.

So, I simply used a WebClient object to download my files.

```
Dim webclient As New WebClient
webclient.Credentials = New NetworkCredential(login, password)
Dim bytesData As Byte() = webclient.DownloadData(addressOfFTPServer + fileNameToDownload)
Return bytesData
```

Hope this will help.